# RadzenSpeechToTextButton fails to work on dotnet on linux asp

Tags: radzen

I use razor page in asp for RadzenSpeechToTextButton. Speach recognition works fine on windows.
It works fine on Windows but once I move project to linux it fails to work with on action
neither any error message. It just fails to work. There is not any message to accept use of microphone in browser like Radzen never asked browser to use microphone.

Code is like followingIndex.razor

```
@using Radzen 
@using Radzen.Blazor  
<RadzenRow>     
  <RadzenColumn Size="6">         
    <RadzenSpeechToTextButton Change="@(args => OnSpeechCaptured(args, false, "Button1"))" />             </RadzenColumn>     
<RadzenColumn Size="6">         
<RadzenSpeechToTextButton Change="@(args => OnSpeechCaptured(args, true, "Button2"))" />           <RadzenTextArea @bind-Value=@value Change=@(args => OnTextAreaChange(args, "TextArea")) class="w-100" Style="margin-top:15px" />     
</RadzenColumn> 
</RadzenRow>  
 @code {     
void OnSpeechCaptured(string speechValue, bool updateTextArea, string name)     
{         if (updateTextArea)         {     
        value += speechValue;         }     
}
 }
```

There is not any error it just not working at all. How to debug it? What to do?

what to do?how to debug it?